# How to run cordova with xcode 7.2?

Tags: cordova, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

I can't find an up and runnig mobile app framework out there. Got the follwing error with my last hope cordova:

```
onsenui-tab-bar  cordova run ios
Running command: /Users/me/Development/onsenui-tab-bar/platforms/ios/cordova/run
simctl was not found.
Check that you have Xcode 6.x installed:

xcodebuild --versionCheck that you have Xcode 6.x selected:
xcode-select --print-path

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: 
Error: /Users/me/Development/onsenui-tab-bar/platforms/ios/cordova/run: 
Command failed with exit code 2 
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

How can I get it run on Mac OSX El Capitan?

Comment: What version of cordova are you on?  Output of `cordova -version` ?

Comment: think you are using an older version of cordova, update it and try
`sudo npm update -g cordova`

Comment: @SimonPrickett I use 5.4.1

Comment: @manukv The command didn't increase the version.

Answer (score 0):

As I've faced the same issue, I guess that this problem is related to Xcode installed for the first time. For me starting Xcode at least once solved the problem.